# Get a list of all aliases and union with name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, .net-6.0

Let's say I have the following entities.

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class ProductAlias
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
}
```

Given a product ID, how could I create a list of all aliases for that product that includes the product `Name` itself in a single query?

I don't know if I can do something like the following. This syntax doesn't work because `Union()` doesn't take a lambda expression.

```
DbContext.Products
    .Where(p => p.Id == productId)
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .Union(p => p.ProductAliases.Select(a => a.Alias))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```cs
var products = DbContext.Products
    .Where(p => p.Id == productId);

products
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .Union(products.SelectMany(p => p.ProductAliases.Select(a => a.Alias)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the equivalent of a SQL Server unpivot like this

```cs
DbContext.Products
    .Where(p => p.Id == productId)
    .SelectMany(p => p.ProductAliases.Select(a => a.Alias).Append(p.Name))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hadn't noticed `Append()` before. Unfortunately, this syntax gives me an error: *`System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Transload.Railtrax.Models.ProductAlias]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Transload.Railtrax.Models.ProductAlias] Where[ProductAlias](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Transload.Railtrax.Models.ProductAlias], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Transload.Railtrax.Models.ProductAlias,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg0')'*

Comment: Hum it appears your LINQ provider doesn't support `Append`. You could maybe try instead `.Concat(new[]{p.Name})` but that probably won't work either. One further option is to write the SQL manually, something like `CROSS APPLY (SELECT p.Name UNION ALL SELECT pa.Alias FROM ProductAlias pa WHERE pa.ProductId = p.ProductId)`. Note that the reason I am pushing these options is because any other option requires reading the tables multiple times.

Comment: I liked the syntax if I could make it work. I'm using SQL Server. So I don't know why it wouldn't be supported.

Comment: I think this it is small chance that EFC will support that, but who knows. At first they have to stabilize current LINQ provider.

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables on `Id` and `ProductId`, select all the needed attribuites
(`Id`, `Name`, `Alias`) and filter on `Id`.

```
products
.Join(aliases, p => p.Id, a => a.ProductId, (p,a) => new { p.Name, p.Id, a.Alias})
.Where(p => p.Id == productId);
```

In another form:

```
(from p in products
    join a in aliases on p.Id equals a.ProductId
    select new  
    {
        p.Name,
        p.Id,
        a.Alias
    })
.Where(p => p.Id == productId);
```

The result (with LINQ2Object for the test, but it should work also with LINQ2SQL):

[image]

Comment: Getting the list of matching aliases is trivial. I want the list to efficiently include the product name as well.